# how to use external Javascript library in vaadin?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I want to use an external js library in my vaadin application.

i installed the library with the command npm install @iota/identity-wasm and now it is inside the node_modules folder.

The JS code can also be executed without any problems, which means that the library is installed correctly.

However, if I set the annotation @JsModule("./register.js") in my Java class, Then I get the error message that the external Js-Bib is not found.

the register.js file is in the frontend folder.

this is how my Java class looks now

```
@Route("")
@NpmPackage(value = "@iota/identity-wasm", version = "0.6.0")
@JsModule("@iota/identity-wasm/node/identity_wasm.js")
@JsModule("./register.js")
public class RegisterView extends VerticalLayout { .... }
```

this is what i get when i go to localhost
[image: this is what i get when i go to localhost]

=============================UPDATE=============================

Thanks to the hint from ( Sascha Ißbrücker ) The frontend can now be compiled successfully. but I still can't execute any Js-code( from the @iota/identity-wasm library) in my Vaadin application.

so the js code should be executed when i click on a button.

this is what my Js code looks like, what I want to execute from my Java code

```
const {AccountBuilder, ExplorerUrl} = require('@iota/identity-wasm/web')

window.register = {
  createDid : async function (){
    console.log("creating identity... This might take some time to complete POW")

    let builder = new AccountBuilder();
    let account = await builder.createIdentity();

    let did = account.did();

    console.log(`Explorer Url:`, ExplorerUrl.mainnet().resolverUrl(did));

    return account.document();
  }

}
```

This is what is should happen after I click my Vaadin button (Java-Code)

```
Button submit = new Button("Submit");

submit.addClickListener(
        event -> UI.getCurrent()
            .getPage()
            .executeJs("return register.createDid()")
            .then(s-> System.out.println(s))

    );
```

Should i do anything else in the java code to make this work ??

best regards

Comment: It looks taht the error comes from the @iota/identity-wasm

Comment: exactly, identity_wasm.js not found, although it is there in the node_modules folder.

Comment: You're importing from `@iota/identity-wasm/node`, which is the Node.js API for the library. You won't be able to transpile this using webpack, or run it in a browser. The NPM page for that library contains separate instructions for how to use the library in a browser: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@iota/identity-wasm.

Comment: @SaschaIßbrücker thank you very much for the hint. please have a look at the update of the question :-)

Comment: I had a similar issue with @web3auth and I made it work. But now on executing a function a modal should appear, but it doesn't. Did you make any progress on your issue?